# Running SpecFlow Scenario Outlines from Test Plans in Azure DevOps (VSTS) or update test plan after test execution

Tags: testing, azure-devops, specflow, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, test-plan

I am using azure devops release pipeline to deploy the tests once the test execute in release it should update test plan. for that i am using visual studio task - option-Test Plan 
Test cases with scenario get updated in test plan but scenario outline is not updating

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to try out below solution. Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow generates multiple test methods for Scenario Outline. However, one test case can only be associated to one test method in Azure devops. I suppose this is why the scenario outline is not updating in your test plan. See [here](https://specsolutions.gitbook.io/specsync/important-concepts/synchronizing-automated-test-cases#test-suite-based-execution-strategy) for more information.

The workaround is to use **Scenario Outline wrappers** as mentioned in above link. Refer below steps.

> For the unit test providers that generate multiple test methods for the Scenario Outlines, SpecSync can generate a special wrapper method, which wraps the execution of the individual Scenario Outline examples and can be associated with the automated test case.

1,Specify `testSuiteBasedExecutionWithScenarioOutlineWrappers` as `testExecutionStrategy` in the `synchronization/automation` section of the configuration file.

```
{
  ...
  "synchronization": {
    ...
    "automation": {
      "enabled": true,
      "testExecutionStrategy": "testSuiteBasedExecutionWithScenarioOutlineWrappers"
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

2, Install the `SpecSync SpecFlow` plugin to your project as a NuGet package. For example for SpecFlow v2.4.*, install SpecSync.AzureDevOps.SpecFlow.2-4.

Check document [Test Suite based execution with Scenario Outline wrappers strategy](https://specsolutions.gitbook.io/specsync/important-concepts/synchronizing-automated-test-cases#test-suite-based-execution-with-scenario-outline-wrappers-strategy) for more information.

Another workaround is to create multiple test cases in azure devops and associate with the test methods generated for the Scenario Outlines one by one.

Comment: No error message in test plan it shows in progress for scenario outline